# I can't use the values ​inside the render item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I can't use the values ​​inside the render item, it doesn't recognize the ItemTrending interface

```
interface ItemTrending {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
}

const TrendingComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [data] = useState<ItemTrending[]>(
    [
      {id: 0, name: 'Nike', description: 'Nike', image: 'www.google.com'},
      {id: 0, name: 'Nike', description: 'Nike', image: 'www.google.com'}
    ]
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Title>{item.name}</Title>
        )}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

{item.**name**} cause:

> The object is of type 'unknown'.

> var item: unknown

I can't find a solution anywhere

**Edit**

solution for the item to be recognized, but this brings up another error in the renderItem function

```
renderItem={({ item }: {item: ItemTrending}) => (
  <Title>{item.name}</Title>
)}
```

> No overload matches this call.

> Provides additional metadata like index if you need it.

Comment: You are using TypeScript and most likely have to define the type of the `item` object

Comment: You're code [works without error](https://tsplay.dev/WYBvdw). So whatever is wrong, it's not a problem with the code you've posted so far.

Comment: It doesn't work here, I don't know where else to look for a solution